# Почему в цикле while не выводит на экран значение включительно? (Особенности цикла while java)

Tags: java, циклы, for, while

// проблема с шагом h = 0.2, в java он идёт например 0.2000001

```
double x1 = -2, x2 = 5, h = 0.2;

while(x1 <= x2){ 
              
    System.out.printf("\n x = %.1f", x1);
    x1 += h;
}
```

Comment: `while (x1 < x2 + h / 2) {`

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/219595/ вот статья на эту тему